# add a new column to a dataframe that will indicate if another column contains a word pyspark

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have a dataframe that i want to add to it a column that will indicate if the word "yes" is in that row text column (1 if the word is in that row 0 if not)
i need to put 1 in check only if "yes" appear as a word and not as a substring
or if "yes" is next to a punctuation mark(example: yes!)
how can i do that in spark?
for example:

```
id  group  text
1   a       hey there
2   c       no you can
3   a       yes yes yes
4   b       yes or no
5   b       you need to say yes.
6   a       yes you can
7   d       yes!
8   c       no&
9   b       ok
```

the result on that will be:

```
id  group  text                  check
1   a       hey there             0
2   c       no you can            0
3   a       yes yes yes           1
4   b       yes or no             1
5   b       you need to say yes.  1
6   a       yes you can           1
7   d       yes!                  1
8   c       no&                   0
9   b       ok                    0
```

Comment: Do you want a spark-only solution, or a SQL solution is viable for you?

Comment: both if you can

Answer (score 3):

You can check with `rlike` and cast to Integer:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn("check",F.col("text").rlike("yes").cast("Integer")).show()
```

---

```
+---+-----+--------------------+-----+
| id|group|                text|check|
+---+-----+--------------------+-----+
|  1|    a|           hey there|    0|
|  2|    c|          no you can|    0|
|  3|    a|         yes yes yes|    1|
|  4|    b|           yes or no|    1|
|  5|    b|you need to say yes.|    1|
|  6|    a|         yes you can|    1|
|  7|    d|                yes!|    1|
|  8|    c|                 no&|    0|
|  9|    b|                  ok|    0|
+---+-----+--------------------+-----+
```

For edited question, you can try with `higher order functions`:

```
import string
import re
pat = '|'.join([re.escape(i) for i in list(string.punctuation)])

(df.withColumn("text1",F.regexp_replace(F.col("text"),pat,""))
.withColumn("Split",F.split("text1"," "))
.withColumn("check",
  F.expr('''exists(Split,x-> replace(x,"","") = "yes")''').cast("Integer"))
.drop("Split","text1")).show()
```

---

```
+---+-----+--------------------+-----+
| id|group|                text|check|
+---+-----+--------------------+-----+
|  1|    a|           hey there|    0|
|  2|    c|          no you can|    0|
|  3|    a|         yes yes yes|    1|
|  4|    b|           yes or no|    1|
|  5|    b|you need to say yes.|    1|
|  6|    a|         yes you can|    1|
|  7|    d|                yes!|    1|
|  8|    c|                 no&|    0|
|  9|    b|               okyes|    0|
+---+-----+--------------------+-----+
```

Comment: i need to put 1 in check only if "yes" appear as a word and not as a substring or if "yes" is next to a punctuation mark(example: yes!)  will that work with your answer?

Comment: @shreder1921 while it is a bad practice to update a question once it has been answered , you can try my edited answer (second part) provided the spark version is 2.4+, check last line for changes

Answer (score 2):

> I need to put `1` in check only if "yes" appear as a word and not as a substring.

You could address this by matching `text` against a regex that uses *word boundaries* (`\b`). This is handy regex feature that represents characters that separate words (spaces, punctuation marks, and so one).

In SQL, you would do:

```
select
    t.*
    case when text rlike '\byes\b' then 1 else 0 end as check
from mytable t
```